# PHP/Ratchet how to process also http requests with webSocket server

Tags: php, http, websocket, ratchet

I am trying to build a WebSocket server which also processes http requests from different source.

One group of channels has to be ws:// because I need them synced, second source of data is server-based and it cannot run over webSockets. Http events should trigger sending ws:// messages to connected clients.

So far I have websocket server in Ratchet which runs great and all, but I fail to communicate with it by http requests.

```
$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new MyApp()
        )
    ),
    8080
);
```

My best guesses are

1. Run second server (in the same script) listening on different port? How to run them both at once?
2. Have the http part in different file, firing events to already running ws server (but passing messages between processes doesnt sound right to me)
3. ... maybe I am missing something

thanks in advance
Ondra

Comment: You need to use the Router component. It allows you to attach different components (WsServer, HttpServer) to different paths.